# existence of a linear code with special parameters

Tags: coding-theory

Prove that there is an $[nN, (n −1)K, 2D]$-linear code over $F_q$ (a finite field) whenever
there is an $ [N, K, D]$-linear code over $F_{q^{n−1}}$ .

All I can think of is putting $n-1$ copies of every codeword after itself...

Comment: I think you mean $F_{q^{n-1}}$. Since $F_{q^{n-1}}$ is an $n-1$-dim. vector space over $F_q$,  I'd write each element of $F_{q^{n-1}}$ as a vector of length $n-1$ with components in $F_q$.

Comment: @Wuestenfux This woud give a $[(n-1)N,(n-1)K,D]$ code, so either the parameters are really mixed up or this is not what OP is looking for...

Comment: Indeed, $2D$ looks strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Encode each element $z\in\Bbb{F}_{q^{n-1}}$, linearly over $\Bbb{F}_q$, to a vector $\phi(z)\in\Bbb{F}_q^n$ by first representing $z$ w.r.t. a chosen basis (giving you a vector $z\in\Bbb{F}_q^{n-1}$) and then adding a checksum symbol to make sure that each non-zero vector $\phi(z)$ has weight $\ge2$.

Comment: In other words, the idea from @Wuestenfux's comment concatenated with an inner $[n,n-1,2]_q$ code at the level of symbols.